# Nested substitution in ZSH

Tags: shell, zsh

I use `zsh`.

Say, for instance, that  I want to remove the current directory from `cdpath`. That means that I need to remove an element based on content, which fits the `${name:#to_be_removed}` pattern nicely. But there's a catch: `to_be_removed` is the result of substitution (namely, `$(pwd)/`). How would I pull this off in a elegant fasion? The best I have managed is this:

```
cdpath=("${(s/ /)$(eval echo $(echo "\${(@)cdpath:#${$(pwd)}/}"))}")
```

This is a common use-case for me, and having tons of this *SH mess is starting to get on my nerves...

Thanks,
PythonNut

Comment: If you are tired of typing this ,,common use-case'', why don't you define a function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the current directory from the `$cdpath` array, I would simply use

```
cdpath=(${cdpath/(#s)$PWD(#e)})
```

`(#s)` and `(#e)` serve the same purpose as `^` and `$` in ,,normal'' regular expressions, i.e. start and end of string. *Please note*: These will need `setopt EXTENDED_GLOB` to work!

If you need an external command,

```
cdpath=(${cdpath/(#s)${$(some_command)}})
```

should work.

Test case:

```
$ setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
$ cdpath=(/foo /foo/bar /bar)
$ pwd
/bar
$ cdpath=(${cdpath/(#s)${$(builtin pwd)}})
$ print -l $cdpath
/foo
/foo/bar
```